# Data stored with localforage does not persist across pages

Tags: javascript, localforage

In my index.html, I saved some data using

```
localforage.getItem('data').then(function(value){
    if (!value) {
        localforage.setItem('data', ["test", "test test"]).then(function(value){
            console.log(value); // this get's displayed on when the data is been created which is the first time the page is loaded.
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
    } else {
        console.log(value); //after saving the value the first, it is always displayed here after page reloads
    }
});
```

Now in my second page which is loaded after loading the first one which means the 'data' must have been saved, I tried retrieving the data using the following code.

```
 localforage.getItem('data').then(function(value){
     console.log(value); // this prints null
 }).catch(function(err) {
     console.log(err);
 });
```

Comment: try `localforage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(["test", "test test"]))`

Comment: If you read my question again you&#39;ll see i used localforage not localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Via try and error I noticed the cause of the problem. Inside the page where the data is been stored, I included the localforage library and another javascript file (database.js) with the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const appName = "testApp";
    const storeName = "test_db";

    localforage.config({
        name: appName,
        storeName: storeName
    });

    localforage.getItem('data').then(function(value) {
        if (!value) {
            localforage.setItem('data', []).then(function(value) {
                console.log(value);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
         }
     })
});
```

Then I went ahead and saved my data using localforage.setItem(). In my second page that I was trying to retrieve the data stored in the browser using localforage, I did not include this javascript. I just included the localforage library and my guess is that when the page was loaded, localforage create a new store with different name. The default name and hence my localforage.getItem() was querying a store which had no data saved in it. Including the database.js made localforage to use the store I configured using localforage.config() and now calling localforage.getItem() in the second page successfully gets data stored from the first page.